# Regularity of Dirichlet Eigenvalues on Lipschitz Domain

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

What kind of regularity do we generally have for weak solutions to the Dirichlet problem?

$$(\Delta+\lambda)u=0 \textrm{ in }U$$

$$u=0 \textrm{ on }\partial U $$

where $U$ is a planar domain with Lipschitz boundary?

I have been told that such domains are nice enough to guarantee classical solutions, but I have not found any references for this.

Comment: Take a look in Brezis book chapter 9: http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analysis-Differential-Equations-Universitext/dp/0387709134

Comment: Thanks for the reference, this book should be quite useful in general. It seems the Dirichlet regularity result in this section assumes at least a $\mathcal{C}^2$ boundary though.

Comment: Yes, it is really useful. What is your definition for classical solutions? In some problems it is only necessary continuity on the boundary and $C^2$ in the interior.

Comment: At least interior $C^2$ and continuous up to boundary. 

My problem only has a piecewise smooth boundary though (but the corners are not too bad, so the domain is still Lipschitz).

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda$ is negative, the problem is $H^1(U)$-elliptic, and an $H^1(U)$ solution exists and is unique.  If $U$ is convex or $C^2$, this solution is $H^2(U)$. If $\Omega$ has some reentrant corner, you can expand the solution in singular functions which vanish away from the reentrant corner.
A good reference may be

> Grisvard: Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains

If $\lambda$ is positive, you may run into trouble if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the Laplacian. Otherwise, the same as above apply (more or less).
For this case, you could have a look at

> Monk: Finite Element Methods for Maxwell's Equations